# What to do about Swing Layout Extensions disappearing?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm looking to migrate a project from Java 8 / NetBeans 8.2 up to Java 10 / NetBeans 9.0.  However, it appears the Swing Layout Extensions library no longer exists, which breaks every form in the project.  I've tried the usual trick of copying the library contents and inserting as a source package, but for whatever reason that's a no go with this particular library (NetBeans fails to find it).  What's the migration path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your post whether you tried the following already, but if you have not, I would try it:

Create a directory somewhere called SwingLayout, and copy the following files into it:

- (NetBeans 8 directory)/platform/modules/ext/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
- (NetBeans 8 directory)/platform/docs/swing-layout-1.0.4-src.zip
- (NetBeans 8 directory)/platform/docs/swing-layout-1.0.4-doc.zip

where (NetBeans 8 directory) is the directory of your most recent version 8 install.

Go to Tools->Libraries, and create a new Library.  Call it "Swing Layout Extension (external)" or whatever you want.  Use the files in the new SwingLayout directory you created, where the ClassPath one is the jar, the Sources one is the one ending in src.zip, and the Javadoc one is the one ending in doc.zip.

Remove the old Swing Layout Extension library from your project, and add the new one.

Comment: Finally got back to this project and could test.  Works perfect!